# Linear voltage regulator footprint does not match with datasheet

Tags: microcontroller, pcb-design, voltage-regulator, schematics

I am designing my prototype (SODAQ ONE V3 BASED ON ARDUINO ZERO WITH A MAX30102 SENSOR) to PCB and I have a doubt with the voltage regulator since firstly:
-The schematic does not show component name, but I have read in SODAQ Board forum and it seems to be the XC6220 (but the [datasheet](https://www.mouser.mx/datasheet/2/760/TOSL_S_A0010556302_1-2575005.pdf) indicates another pin configuration ):
[image]

While the [schematic](https://support.sodaq.com/Boards/One/SODAQ_ONE_v3.pdf) shows:
[image]
I also read other variant of sodaq board ([Sodaq Explorer](https://support.sodaq.com/Boards/ExpLoRer/explorer_schematic_rev6c_915.pdf) and it uses the [MCP1711 linear voltage regulator](https://www.mouser.mx/datasheet/2/268/MCHP_S_A0002779618_1-2576388.pdf) but in the same way the symbol and footprint do not match but the symbol in the schematic is exactly the same as the one shown above.
Could somebody explain me? Thank you!

Comment: The SOT-25 matches if the numbering of the pins is done in the same way as in the datasheet? The same for the SOT-23 of the MCP1711.

Comment: @Arsenal That is true, the SOT-25 matches to the XC6220 and the CE corresponds to EN (in the schematic) and NC to BP pin. Thank you so much!

Comment: I don't see any discrepancy here. Please spell out what you think is the problem.

Comment: The schematic has no visible pin numbers so you don't know if they match or not. This can't be answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like they used the same IC (XC6220 as you guessed) that they used in [Autonomo](https://support.sodaq.com/Boards/Autonomo/sodaq_autonomo_rev1_sch_v1.pdf).

Even [One's base board](https://support.sodaq.com/Boards/One/SODAQ_ONE_base.pdf) has the same regulator, as seen clearly.